# Calculating distance between starting point to destination using Google maps V2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, google-places-api

I have one starting point and various stops, so I want to calculate the **distance** between them. I used this reference[Please check](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

After calculating distance and duration I want to bind that data in **list** using **list adapter**. At last am able to calculate all the distances and duration but failed to bind the data in list. Am getting **Null pointer exception** in my listview adapter because list generates before I got response from api.

Any help will be Appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: I hope you can post some code where do you have error and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you've not posted any code, I'll give you a slightly generic answer that could help you.

Put a try catch around the initial assignment to the listview, so as to avoid it from causing the app to crash.

Then, after you've managed to calculate all the distances you desire, tell the list adapter that the data set has changed by using:

```
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Make sure its after your dataset to fill the list with has been acquired.

This will cause the list to "refresh" itself, thereby making it visible in the listview.